# Android custom dialog linearlayout size same as dialogs bg image

Tags: android, layout, dialog, size

I am creating a custom dialog as:

```
    Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.Theme_Levels);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.levelselector);
    myDialog.show();
```

Style used:

```
<style name="Theme.Levels" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
   <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dlgbg</item>
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
   <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LevelSelector" 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
  android:paddingBottom="50dip"
  >     

    <Button android:text="Easy" 
        android:id="@+id/btn_Easy" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the button to appear at bottom center of the dialog (50dip padding from bottom) but it appears at top left of the Dialog.

Thats because LinearLayout does not know the width/height of the dialog, which is the size of the background image I have used in style xml file.

Question: How do I know the width height of the dialog so that LinearLayout is of the same size as the Dialog size?

Comment: set layout_gravity for button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a way, not a clean way but works.

You need to add background in style.xml file

```
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/levelselectbg</item>
```

AND also in you linearlayout:

```
android:background="@drawable/levelselectbg"
```

The first background is required to keep the dialog borderless (which I have specified in my style.xml in my question) and the linearlayout background is required to give size to the layout, now it knows its dimensions and places the button at bottom center with padding.

Hope this helps someone, if a better solution is available please share.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/LevelSelector" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingBottom="50dip" >     

    <View
       android:layout_width="0dp" 
       android:layout_height="0dp" 
       android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button android:text="Easy" 
        android:id="@+id/btn_Easy" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It does go at the bottom with 50dip padding but its left aligned.

Comment: Make sure `android:orientation="vertical"` is added to `LinearLayout`.

Comment: It is already added. I am using the exact code you have posted. Another issue is that background image is stretched to cover the whole screen height wise (i am using landscape), although its smaller than screen size. When I remove <View> tag bg image size shows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"` to `android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`. 
`android:layout_gravity` is gravity of the layout itself w.r.t. its parent. `android:gravity` applies to its contents.

Comment: No, unfortunately this did not work. Answer from Inazaruk did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in my case i ended up using a `RelativeLayout`

here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/body" android:layout_margin="20dip"    
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg" 
>

<TextView android:id="@+id/message"     
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:layout_margin="10dip" 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"       
    android:textColor="@color/table_text"
    android:textScaleX=".95" android:textStyle="bold"       
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/dummy" android:layout_below="@id/message" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="60dip"        
    android:visibility="invisible" 
/>  
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip" android:layout_below="@id/message" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ok" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_alert" android:src="@drawable/btn_yes"
        android:visibility="gone" android:layout_weight=".5"
    />  
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/cancel" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:background="@drawable/button_alert" android:src="@drawable/btn_no"
        android:visibility="gone" android:layout_weight=".5"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using custom dialog? You have specified background in your relativelayout not in your style xml? The main issue I face when I put bg in layout is that its border does not remain hidden, which I have set to null in my style xml file.

Comment: This layout is adding items by specifying layout_below attribute, and it won't work if I only have one button to show at the bottom with just an image in the background.